# *ngIf=item.activityStatus!=("Done") as angular2 conditional visibility

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to toggle the visibility of a button based of a value of an item

Here is my code:

```
 <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of statusConfig | slice:0:9; let i = index;" >
                  <td class="col-md-1">
                    {{item.id}}
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">
                    {{item.activityName}}
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">
                    {{item.activityStatus}}
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">
                    {{item.activityDateEpoch | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">
                    <button *ngIf=item.activityStatus!=("Done") type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveStatus(item.id, i)">Mark as done</button>
                  </td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

why is this a syntax error and how should I fix this?

```
directive_normalizer.js:82 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "button" ("tyStatus!="Done" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveStatus(item.id, i)">Mark as done[ERROR ->]</button>
                  </td>

"): ReportComponent@45:145
```

and

```
activityStatus = "Done" for now
```

Comment: Can you provide us value of item.activityStatus and syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in shock how many mistakes you managed to make in one line of code. :-)

**First**: `NgIf` directive accepts `string` as expression value, which means it has to have the following form:

```
*ngIf="expression here"
```

**Second**: You can't use `"` two times, if you want to use `string` in `"`, you should use single quotes then (`'`)

**Third**: Brackets are not needed: `("Done")`

Anyway, your expression should look like this:

```
*ngIf="item.activityStatus != 'Done'"
```

You can read more about `NgIf` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html).

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
*ngIf="(item.activityStatus!='Done')"
```